# Can I get the timezone in valid format which can be used by python directly from microsoft graph API while getting schedule of user?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

API Example:

I want user's working hours with timezone, I've used getSchedule api to get it

But it's giving time zone which is directly incompatible with python

So, I want timezone as "Asia/Kolkata" not "India Standard Time"

Because I want to implement it in python as follows

```
import pytz

indian_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
```

```
POST /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/calendar/getSchedule
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"
Content-Type: application/json

{        
    "schedules": ["adelev@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", "meganb@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"],
    "startTime": {
        "dateTime": "2019-03-15T09:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "dateTime": "2019-03-15T18:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "availabilityViewInterval": 60
}
```

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
    "value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "msft@msft.com",
            "availabilityView": "0000000",
            "scheduleItems": [],
            "workingHours": {
                "daysOfWeek": [
                    "monday",
                    "tuesday",
                    "wednesday",
                    "thursday",
                    "friday"
                ],
                "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
                "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": {
                    "name": "India Standard Time"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And  I need timezone as

```
 "timeZone": {
        "name": "Asia/Kolkata"
 }
```

Can I get it with any way with application level credential?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to point2 mentioned in [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-pythondjangoapp/blob/main/tutorial/05-add-ms-graph.md) sample. This is necessary because Microsoft Graph can return time zones as Windows time zone names, and the Python DateTime library requires IANA time zone identifiers.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: The sample leads to a 404